# Where are dll files stored from metabots

Tags: dll, automationanywhere

What I want to do is to check the full logic someones else metabot that was uploaded to repository, or donwloaded from AAE BotStore.

When I'm creating my own metabot in Automation Anywhere I need to pass to AAE IDE dll file. 
But when I'm uplaoding it to the server I'm uploading just Metabot without this dll file.

[image]

So to sum up I want to locate the dll file that is responsible for Metabot’s logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLL is actually stored in the .mbot file.  If you find the .mbot file in the windows folder directory using Windows File explorer and rename the file extension to .zip from .mbot, you will see it is really a zip file and that inside that zip file is the dll files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're being limited by your Control Room permissions. AAE has system defined permissions in this area, which are pre-configured during Control Room installation. For more details on this, please see [AAE's supporting documentation](https://support.automationanywhere.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003197914-Create-a-role?flash_digest=4750844848634bc016f6769cb2704ddd32f7438e). For example, if you were granted the "AAE_Meta Bot Designer" role in the Control Room you would be allowed to "access MetaBot Designer from AAE Client but not allowed to see any bots and/or **supporting files**."